How to update build.gradle to use media3 packages from version 33 to 34?
I'm trying to build a video player and I'm running into a build issue. When I add these 3 dependencies
  implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.1")
  implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.3.1")
  implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.3.1")

I start getting build errors like this:
1.  Dependency 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.3.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
       Android APIs.
 
       :app is currently compiled against android-33.
 
       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 7.4.2 is 33.
 
       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
       compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
 
       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

I have tried updating compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 34 but that didn't help. Here is my full build.gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
group = 'expo.modules.webview'
version = '0.5.0'
buildscript {
  def expoModulesCorePlugin = new File(project(":expo-modules-core").projectDir.absolutePath, "ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle")
  if (expoModulesCorePlugin.exists()) {
    apply from: expoModulesCorePlugin
    applyKotlinExpoModulesCorePlugin()
  }

  // Simple helper that allows the root project to override versions declared by this library.
  ext.safeExtGet = { prop, fallback ->
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
  }
  // Ensures backward compatibility
  ext.getKotlinVersion = {
    if (ext.has("kotlinVersion")) {
      ext.kotlinVersion()
    } else {
      ext.safeExtGet("kotlinVersion", "1.9.20")
    }
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${getKotlinVersion()}")
  }
}
afterEvaluate {
  publishing {
    publications {
      release(MavenPublication) {
        from components.release
      }
    }
    repositories {
      maven {
        url = mavenLocal().url
      }
    }
  }
}
android {
  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet("compileSdkVersion", 34)

  def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
  if (agpVersion.tokenize('.')[0].toInteger() < 8) {
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.majorVersion
    }
  }

  namespace "expo.modules.webview"
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet("minSdkVersion", 21)
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet("targetSdkVersion", 34)
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.5.0"
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  publishing {
    singleVariant("release") {
      withSourcesJar()
    }
  }
  // Enables Compose functionality
  buildFeatures {
    compose true
  }
  // Kotlin compiler version must be tied to Kotlin version
  // according: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin
  composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.10"
  }
}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation project(':expo-modules-core')
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${getKotlinVersion()}"
  implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.1")
  implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.3.1")
  implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.3.1")
  // Importing Jetpack Compose
  implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"))
  // and ui library
  implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
  // OPTIONAL - Android Studio Preview support
  implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
  debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")

}


What is your gradle version?
As per the error, you are probably using an old version of gradle

Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34

Try using something like 8.4 and that should fix your issue.

Android SDK Version 34 compatible libraries
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-common:1.2.0"

